# How is the value of this form object set? (re: Railscast #235 Devise & OmniAuth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, devise

I am following along Railscast #235 Devise and OmniAuth. I do not understand how the form fields for password and password_confirmation are dynamically hidden from the form.

On the form, the line `f.object.password_required?` evaluates whether or not to include that password fields (and the `password_required?` method is also used to override validations). **But**, how and where is `f.object` set at all?

As I understand the code, I user clicks "Register through Twitter". A session is then set, storing the Twitter OmniAuth info and the user is redirected to the Devise Registration page. Somehow the "f.object" is set, and the password_required? method is run on it. If the `f.object` does not require a password, the fields are hidden.

How is the `f.object` set?

I have included the relevant code from the Railscast.

**User Object**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

# Apply OmniAuth hash to model
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.username = auth.info.nickname
    end
end

# Override Devise hook
def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
        new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: :true) do |user|
            user.attributes = params
            user.valid?
        end
    else
        super
    end
end

# Override Devise password_required?
def password_required?
    super && provider.blank?
end
end
```

**OmniauthCallbacks Controller**

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if user.persisted?
        sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
        session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
end

alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

**Devise Registration View**

```
    <h2>Sign up</h2>

    <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :username, required: true, autofocus: true %>   
    <%= f.input :email %>

    <% if f.object.password_required? %>
      <%= f.input :password, required: true %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
    <% end %>

  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up" %>
  </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```